# G note on my guitar dies out quickly and has a 'thump' kind of noise

Tags: acoustic-guitar, sustain

I have a Merida DG 15-SPOMCES guitar. It is a nice resonant guitar but sadly the G note just doesn't sound as good as other notes especially on the 10th fret of the 5th string (is little better on the 5th fret of the 4th string and a little better on the third string - the open G). The note produces a 'thump' kind of noise and dies out quickly. Can anyone explain the reason for this and any possible remedy? I would be very grateful for any response! Thank you!

Comment: Have you inspected the nut and bridge?  There could be something caught near there that's deadening the sound.

Comment: only G and on three different strings in three different fret locations?

Comment: Yes, I had removed all the strings and checked inside I could find nothing suspicious. And yes, it is only G on the top three strings. The problem remains the same even if i change the scale of the strings, the problem just shifts to other frets.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation matches exactly the phenomenon of a *dead spot*: a resonance in the guitar's neck that causes the mechanical impedance at that frequency to almost vanish, thus quickly draining that note's energy.

This isn't an issue many guitarists think too much about (though quite a few instruments have slight dead spots, they're usually not so pronounced that it's really a problem), but it's quite a common plague for bass, [and people think a lot about good solutions](https://www.bestbassgear.com/ebass/gear/hardware/tuner/treating-your-basses-deadspot.html). Most tricks amount to altering the neck's response through extra mass, generally at the free space on the headstock. The most crude implement for this is a woodworking C-clamp, but perhaps a capodaster will already do or a clip tuner – both are useful to have the anyway! There are also purpose-built weights available, Fender markets this under the name *fatfinger*.

The problem can also have something to do with a badly embedded truss rod; a luthier might be able to tell.

Comment: That seems the most likely problem to me too.  Another possibility is a resonance in the body that absorbs a particular frequency.  But I suspect this is more likely in violins and cellos than in guitars.

Comment: Would you suggest any solution to it!

Comment: @Amish: write `@ScottWallace` to reply to another commenter so they will then be notified. Or were you accosting me? In case this is due to a neck resonance, I already gave suggestions.